# Excel - Copying formulas across when there is a blank column in between

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Trying to copy a formula across 13 columns that have a blank column between each - so 26 columns in total.  The formula gets data from another spreadsheet.  At the moment I am going to each cell and copying the formula in and modifying the reference cell.  Is there any way to make this quicker.  I have tried dragging and copying when I have had 2 formulas filled in correctly however that does not work.

It wouldn't be so bad but it involves about 8 or 9 of these rows.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the cell with the formula and the empty cell next to it. Using the fill handle, drag the corner ACROSS to the desired column. Excel will follow the pattern and copy the formula to the cell in every other column.

[image]

Then, if you need to, drag the corner DOWN to the desired number of rows.

If you are not getting the results you expect, you may need to adjust your formula in order for it to be copied correctly. That would be a different question though.